# LINUX / PERL : split a single line into multiple lines

Tags: linux, perl

My content of my input file - test:

```
tang 123 gene gene 3000 1000 4000
```

- the 5h column is the size of the gene in base pair.
- the 6th column is the starting point of the gene location;
- the 7th column is the end point of the gene location.

I would like to divide this line into multiple line of 600 base pair each until/before the ending point.

I want the result like this:

```
tang 123 gene gene 600 1000 1600 
tang 123 gene gene 600 1600 2200 
tang 123 gene gene 600 2200 2800 
tang 123 gene gene 600 2800 3400
tang 123 gene gene 600 3400 4000
```

What should I do in order to come out these result? Can I just write a command line or need to write a script?

Comment: You should learn the basics of Perl programming, first. Then you will able to answer your question yourself and actually write the script or one-liner.

Comment: What if 5th column not a multiple of 600?

Comment: @Alextang992, I was wrong! your current approach of posting 'do-it-for-me' questions here is working quite well. You can completely disregard my advice about learning some programming language!

Comment: @salva: Are you the one downvoting all the answers because you don't like the question?

Answer (score 3):

Quick one liner:

```
echo tang 123 gene gene 3000 1000 4000 |\
perl -ale '$F[4] = 600; print "@F[0..5] ",$F[5]+=$F[4] while $F[5] < $F[6]'
```

For each line, split it into fields 0 to 6, and replace field 4 with 600.

Then print fields 0..5, increment field 5 by field 4 and print it in place of field 6, while field 5 is smaller than field 6.

Answer (score -1):

awk code:

```
echo "tang 123 gene gene 600 1000 4000" | awk '{prefix=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5;step=$5;start=$6;end=$7} END{for(i=start;i<end;i+=step) {tmp=i+step; print prefix" "i" "(tmp<end?tmp:end)}}'
```

result:

```
tang 123 gene gene 600 1000 1600
tang 123 gene gene 600 1600 2200
tang 123 gene gene 600 2200 2800
tang 123 gene gene 600 2800 3400
tang 123 gene gene 600 3400 4000
```

if input is "tang 123 gene gene 700 1000 4000"

result:

```
tang 123 gene gene 700 1000 1700
tang 123 gene gene 700 1700 2400
tang 123 gene gene 700 2400 3100
tang 123 gene gene 700 3100 3800
tang 123 gene gene 700 3800 4000
```